# LESS vs. COMPASS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, less, compass-sass, css-frameworks

For a rails CSS framework for an existing app, which one do you prefer - LESS or COMPASS?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Less and Compass are not really direct competitors.

LESS is a CSS engine. Compass is more a toolbox around SASS/SCSS and Blueprint CSS framewok. So if you want to use Blueprint in your project, use Compass.

You should take a look at LESS syntax and SCSS syntax and choose the one your prefer. But they both are now a superset of CSS 3 and they have more or less the same features.

Another thing to know is that SCSS/SASS is still included in HAML gem. So if you want to use HAML...

Comment: Just one tiny correction even though Compass was born out of Blueprint  it now supports several CSS frameworks.